# Shorted BIAS on AVR Receiver

Tags: mosfet, pcb, repair

I have a Denon x1200w and had the red blinking light of death. Took it apart, found one of the mosfets on the power board bad, replaced it. And all was well. Except the left channel was distorted and I realized I forgot to adjust the BIAS for that channel. So I take it apart and start to adjust it and my 2 multimeter leads come in contact and I see a spark and a pop and some fun smoke from one of the caps. Now, the mosfet on that channel is bad so I replace that and the cap that blew, however I can't get it to turn on anymore. I'm back to the blinking red light. Any ideas what else I can look at to solve this issue?

Attached an image of the area I shorted. I stuck the leads into the CN550 like an idiot, and the cap directly to the right of it blew.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Get the schematic and start measuring voltages. To get a better answer would require someone who has intimate knowledge of the unit in question.

Comment: If it was me, I'd buy a used X1200 that works, and chalk the price up as an educational expense. It's a lesson learned about how to work with semiconductor electronics.